# multiple builds of same project

Tags: ant, web-deployment

i want to deploy a java web application.but with some changes i need to use the same application for trail also. the difference is an additional package.by using Ant or some other tools, is it possible?i need to deploy the applications as two war file.sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using Ant.  You can create two separate targets, one for each war, and then run both of them in your build.

```
<project name="Proj" default="package" basedir=".">
   <target name="package" depends="war1,"war2" />

   <target name="war1">
    ...  build the first WAR
   </target>
   <target name="war2">
    ...  build the second WAR
   </target>
</project>
```

If you find the targets are repetitive you can break common parts out into smaller targets or you can use `macrodef` to create macro let's you run similar targets with different parameters.

Comment: thank u so much Dave DeCaprio.how to exclude some packages ? exclude tag can be used?